# PDFRenderer zoom and flips

Tags: android, imageview, gesture, pdfrenderer

My PDF Renderer has following concern -

1. when i zoom image view, the page gets zoomed along with that the page is either moved to the next or previous page..the page is NOT held..
2. I have implemented the flips using xml and the zoom using gesture Listener both seem to be overriding...any suggestions please??

public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent touchevent) {

```
int actionId = touchevent.getPointerCount();

if (actionId == 1 && touchevent.getPointerCount() == 2) {
    switch (touchevent.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
    // when user first touches the screen to swap
    {
        flag = 0;
        System.out.println("ACTION_DOWN - "
                + touchevent.getPointerCount());
        lastX = touchevent.getX();
        break;
    }

    // Finger went up
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
        flag = 0;
        float currentX = touchevent.getX();
        System.out.println("ACTION_UP - "
                + touchevent.getPointerCount());
        // if left to right swipe on screen - previous page
        if (lastX < currentX) {
            // If no more View/Child to flip
            // if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
            // break;

            Log.e("TAG -  in prevoius move", "TAG - in prevoius move");
            Log.i("TAG - BEFORE MOVE ", "currentPage - " + currentPage);
            if (currentPage > 0) {
                try {
                    render(--currentPage);
                    if (!next.isEnabled())
                        next.setEnabled(true);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } else {
                currentPage = 0;
                try {
                    render(currentPage);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                previous.setEnabled(false);
                if (!next.isEnabled())
                    next.setEnabled(true);
            }
            Log.i("TAG - POST PREVIOUS MOVE ", "currentPage - "
                    + currentPage);

            // set the required Animation type to ViewFlipper
            // The Next screen will come in form Left and current Screen
            // will go OUT from Right
            // Specifies the animation used to animate a View that
            // enters / exits the screen.
            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_left);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_right);
            // Show the next Screen
            viewFlipper.showNext();
        }

        // if right to left swipe on screen - next page
        if (lastX > currentX) {
            // if (viewFlipper.getDisplayedChild() == 1)
            // break;

            Log.e("TAG -  in next move", " TAG - in next move");
            Log.i("TAG - BEFORE MOVE ", "currentPage - " + currentPage);
            if (currentPage < renderer.getPageCount()) {
                try {
                    if (currentPage == renderer.getPageCount() - 1) {
                        next.setEnabled(false);
                        // currentPage--;
                        // render(currentPage);
                    } else {
                        render(++currentPage);
                        if (!next.isEnabled())
                            next.setEnabled(true);
                        if (!previous.isEnabled())
                            previous.setEnabled(true);
                    }
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            Log.i("TAG - POST NEXT MOVE ", "currentPage - "
                    + currentPage);

            // set the required Animation type to ViewFlipper
            // The Next screen will come in form Right and current
            // Screen will go OUT from Left
            // Specifies the animation used to animate a View that
            // enters / exits the screen.
            viewFlipper.setInAnimation(this, R.anim.in_from_right);
            viewFlipper.setOutAnimation(this, R.anim.out_to_left);
            // Show The Previous Screen
            viewFlipper.showPrevious();
        }

    }
    }
} else {
    flag = 1;
    SGD.onTouchEvent(touchevent);
    System.out.println("SGD - " + touchevent.getPointerCount());
}

return false;
```

}

private void render(int i) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

```
private class ScaleListener extends
            ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {
        @Override
         public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
          scale *= detector.getScaleFactor();
          scale = Math.max(0.1 f, Math.min(scale, 5.0 f));
          matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
          imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);

          return true;
         }
    }
```

Comment: any update on this question?